# Java Dice Game Trouble Generating new numbers

Tags: java, class, object, random, instance

I am trying to learn OOP, starting with Java as I have read and been told it's the best place to start. With that said, I am trying to create a game for fun to help my learning, but I also know game programming and design can be more challenging.

So my goal here is to generate a new value from the RollDice D20 without having to reset or restart the program. You'll notice when I print out the values I print the same instance twice to demonstrate what I am avoiding, and a new instance to show that the new instance does indeed generate a new value. Perhaps, I am not approaching this in the right way, but this is a hurdle I am hoping to overcome with some help!

What I ultimately want is to figure out how to generate a new instance or at least a new roll value as many times as I want. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! I have added the code below as an example. Also any other feedback is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

class RollDice
{// Begin RollDice Class


    // Initiate method rollDice
    public static int rollDice(int number, int nSides)
    {
        // System.out.println( "--- Welcome to the Dice Game v2! ---" ); //
        // welcomes player

        Random r = new Random();
        // Declare class variables
        int num = 0;
        int roll = 0;

        if (nSides >= 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                roll = r.nextInt(nSides) + 1;
                // System.out.println("Roll is: " + roll);
                num = num + roll;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error num needs to be from 3");
        }
        return num;
    } // end method rollDice

    int d4 = rollDice(1, 4);
    int d6 = rollDice(1, 6);
    int d8 = rollDice(1, 8);
    int d10 = rollDice(1, 10);
    int d12 = rollDice(1, 12);
    int d20 = rollDice(1, 20);

    public RollDice()

    {
        this.d4 = d4;
    }

    public void setD4(int D4)
    {
        this.d4 = D4;
    }

    public int getD4()
    {
        return d4;
    }

    // ////////////////
    {
        this.d6 = d6;
    }

    public void setD6(int D6)
    {
        this.d6 = D6;
    }

    public int getD6()
    {
        return d6;
    }

    // ////////////////
    {
        this.d8 = d8;
    }

    public void setD8(int D8)
    {
        this.d8 = D8;
    }

    public int getD8()
    {
        return d8;
    }

    // ////////////////
    {
        this.d10 = d10;
    }

    public void setD10(int D10)
    {
        this.d10 = D10;
    }

    public int getD10()
    {
        return d10;
    }

    // ////////////////
    {
        this.d12 = d12;
    }

    public void setD12(int D12)
    {
        this.d12 = D12;
    }

    public int getD12()
    {
        return d12;
    }

    // ////////////////
    {
        this.d20 = d20;
    }

    public void setD20(int D20)
    {
        this.d20 = D20;
    }

    public int getD20()
    {
        return d20;
    }
    // ////////////////
}// End RollDice Class

class Champion
{// Begin Champion Class

    RollDice champDice = new RollDice();
    int champroll = champDice.getD20();

    public Champion()
    {
        this.champroll = champroll;
    }

    public void setChampRoll(int ChampRoll)
    {
        this.champroll = ChampRoll;
    }

    public int getChampRoll()
    {
        return champroll;
    }
}// End Champion Class

public class DiceRollTest
{
    public static void main(String ars[])
    {
        Champion tChampion = new Champion();
        Champion pChampion = new Champion();
        System.out.println("Your Champion defends with a " + tChampion.getChampRoll() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Your Champion defends with a " + tChampion.getChampRoll() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Your Champion defends with a " + pChampion.getChampRoll() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear?

Comment: This line: `this.champroll = champroll;` (as well as `this.d4 = d4;`) has no effect since this.champroll is exactly champroll. It would have some effect if your construct would take it as a parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your RollDice class is not accomplishing what you want.  All it's doing is storing a single dice roll result for each type of dice you have.  Therefore, when you go an call getChampRoll() on your Champion object, all it's doing is returning the roll that already took place when you constructed your RollDice class.

Instead, you should make rollDice() a member function of your RollDice class.  RollDice should then take in its constructor an argument indicating which dice should be rolled when rollDice() is called.  That way, when you call getD20(), it will roll the D20 and give you the result.

I'll leave you with this as a starting point:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die {

    private int mSides;
    private Random mRandom;

    public Die(int sides) {
        this.mSides = sides;
        mRandom = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public int roll() {
        return mRandom.nextInt(mSides + 1);
    }

    public int roll(int times) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            sum += roll();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

This class can be inherited/subclassed for each dice you want to create.  Then you can toss a few of these in your champion's pockets :)

Comment: bstar, while I'm not 100% how to go about this, it makes A LOT more sense to me now and I appreciate you forcing me to learn. As much as it sucks sometimes, I have learned a great deal by spending time figuring out my own solutions and testing different things. I will certainly post back here with my results when I create a solution!

Comment: @CoShark I'm glad you're willing to learn, and for that, I put up a hint.

Comment: I would write the same class.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create new Constructor. In this constructor you should inicialize Random object, and probably how many sides will dice have

```
class RollDice{
    Random rand;
    int sides;
    public RollDice(int x){
        sides = x;
        rand = new Random()
    }
}
```

then, in that class you can add method which will generate new value

```
public int roll(){
    return rand.nextInt(x);
}
```

you may as well don,t generate RollDice object with fixed value of dice's sides and make the method like:

```
public int roll(int x){
    return rand.nextInt(x);
}
```

if you want java to generate new value after you enter something on console just use loop with System.in.read() and if or switch statement (for example if someone enters 1 - generate new value, if 0, end program)